# Searching RSS feeds in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I build a site on Drupal CMS and added some external RSS feeds. The search block works fine when i publish node, means it can search the nodes. But feeds are not stored as nodes so how do search the feed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE - Jan 2012: The [feeds](http://drupal.org/node/326601) module has succeeded the FeedAPI module.*

I have never used it yet, but you might take a look at the module called [FeedAPI](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi) , which *(quoting that page)* :

> FeedAPI aggregates feeds on a Drupal
>   website by generating light weight
>   items or nodes from feeds.

You can also look it's [wiki-documentation page](http://drupal.org/node/326601), which has some interesting informations, like :

> FeedAPI will parse RSS feeds and turns
>   the items within those "aggregated"
>   RSS feeds into nodes. This opens up a
>   plethora of new features that the
>   Drupal core Aggregator Module's
>   lightweight items cannot offer.

I don't see anything that says that these can be searched... But as the RSS feeds are imported into nodes, those should be.

*Hope this help :-)*

Comment: Thanks Pascal Martin for the response I will see if it works and get back to you.